How to apply coupon code to bluesnap API `/recurring/subscriptions`
I am using bluesnap payment gateway. I am creating subscription using /recurring/subscriptions endpoint. I have created some coupon codes but I can't find anything related to parameter that will accept coupon code while creating subscription.
How to apply coupon code to subscription in /recurring/subscriptions?
current body of /recurring/subscriptions:
payerInfo: {
    zip?: string | null;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    phone?: number | null;
  };
  paymentSource: {
    creditCardInfo: {
      creditCard: {
        expirationYear: number;
        securityCode: number;
        expirationMonth: string;
        cardNumber: number;
      };
    };
  };
  additionalInfo: {
    address?: string | null;
    companyName?: string | null;
    companyNumber?: number | null;
  };
  planId: number;

